# Does a Stack Exchange press kit exist?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-promotion

Press Kits are pieces of promotional material that provide information on a person, company, organization or topic.  They have been traditionally used by news and other media outlets to promote a new film, tv show, or video game (among other things) and contain various copy, fact sheets, and images.

Is there a Stack Exchange press kit available?  What about press kits for the top Stack Exchange sites?  What is the process if a news outlet wants to produce a story on Stack Exchange (if any)?

Comment: Why would SE know if other big sites have press kits?

Comment: @Catija other big Stack Exchange sites (Stack Overflow, Super User, etc).  I'll edit for clarity.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. The press kit is on the "[about us](https://stackoverflow.com/company/about)" page. Scroll down to the blue horizontal section at the bottom of the page.

This relates to the company, Stack Overflow, and seems to be common to all SE sites.

Comment: To clarify: the page contains the words  "Press Kit" followed by a link to [Download Logos](https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos) and a link to http://stackoverflow.blog/. This may or may not match one's idea of a "Press Kit".